# Prove that if $x^k \equiv n \pmod {n^2}$ then $n=y^k$ for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory

I've encountered the following problem:

Prove that if $x^k \equiv n \pmod {n^2}$ for some $x\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $n=y^k$ for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I failed to solve it. I tried decomposing $n = p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_l^{r_l}$. It is easily seen that $x$ must be composed of the same prime factors, and maybe more: $x = p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_l^{e_l}\cdot p_{l+1}^{e_{l+1}}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$. And then:

$$x^k \equiv n \pmod {n^2}$$
$$p_1^{ke_1}\cdots p_l^{ke_l}\cdot p_{l+1}^{ke_{l+1}}\cdots p_m^{ke_m}=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_k^{r_k}\: \mod  p_1^{2r_1}\cdots p_l^{2r_l}$$

But it gets very messy. What I really want to show is that $k|r_i$, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $p\mid n$ or more precisely $p^r\|n$ (i.e., $p^r\mid n$ and $p^{r+1}\nmid n$) with $r\ge 1$.
Also, assume $p^s\|x$ with $s\ge 0$. 
then $x^k\equiv n\pmod{n^2}$ implies $p^{r}\|x^k$ (we're using $p^{r+1}\mid n^2$ here). As also $p^{ks}\|x^k$ we conclude $r=ks$.
Hence the exponent of any prime dividing $n$ is a multiple of $k$, which means that $n$ is a $k$th power.